# Dispute resolution in smart contracts - ex. Kleros & Aragon

Tags: blockchain, immutability, smartcontracts, dao

I have been diving into Smart Contracts and dispute resolution platforms, such as Aragon, Kleros... The question I have right now is within the basic principle of immutability of Smart contracts.

If I have an sc about buying a product, a design of a webpage, and if I am not satisfied with it, and the developer thinks she/he did the job well, there is a dispute. I will go to one of these platforms and ask for a dispute resolution, but what happens with my funds? They would be locked on the ESCROW Smart Contract, until the dispute is settled? After the court decided, for ex. in my favour, I would get my funds back, but isn't that the opposite of what my contract had to do? Isn't that changing the execution of the smart contract, and reversing the transaction?

And also, if the sc is executed, and afterwards, I figure out oh it is missing some features I wanted, can I also then apply for a dispute resolution or no?

Answer (score 1):

The trade logic won’t be executed until dispute settles.

Example:

Alice hires Bob to make a website for Alice. Terms of this task is defined by an agreement. Alice pays the price of the task to smart contract (not to Bob, yet) and waits Bob to deliver the website. If Bob delivers and Alice accepts, smart contract releases the payment to Bob. Otherwise payment gets disputed and it will be released either to Alice or Bob depending on dispute resolution outcome.

So, there is no reversing of execution. Instead, payment is temporarily escrowed inside the smart contract.

Disclaimer: I’m a developer of Kleros.